# redirect a file generated by a program to another program

Tags: linux, pipe

In linux enviroment, I have a program that creates a large file (2-3GB). I need to filter this file (e.g. I want to remove a line if it appears in the precedeing 10 lines). I want to do it while the program is running and without creating a new file.

If the program directed the output to stdout instead of a file it could be easily solved by piping (prgram1 | filter_program > file). But this is not the case.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

### mkfifo

You could have your first program write to a fifo (named pipe) instead of a regular file, then you can process the output as you like as in a normal pipe:

```
mkfifo out
prgram1 -O out | filter_program < out  > file
rm out
```

For example, with wget as prgram1 you could do:

```
wget -qO out 'superuser.com' | grep '<title>' out
```

The `|` just serves to run both commands simultaneously, the pipe itself is not used.

The program must be writing the file sequentially for this to work. If it needs to move around the file that won't do.

---

**Edit:** This doesn't work if program deletes output file before writing.

We need some more trickery then. How about letting program [write but not delete the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869536/linux-directory-permissions-read-write-but-not-delete/869554#869554) :

```
$ prg1() { rm out; wget -qO out 'superuser.com'; }
$ mkfifo out
$ chmod 500 .
$ prg1 | grep '<title>' out
```

That should work as long as program isn't too fussy and doesn't error out on failed delete.

Comment: It seems to be a great solution. But in my case program1 deletes previous output files before starting and then **creates a new output file** (that is not a named pipe). It doesn't append its output to existing file. Can I transform this regular output file into a named pipe?

Comment: First thing i'd try is preventing it from removing it. I just edited my answer.